# Media gallery thumbnails 1px

Tags: media-library

So I exported/imported images from one site to another (don't even want to get into the headache that has been causing!!)

The latest issue is that it appears that all of my images have copied over properly (other than none of them are attached to their pages/posts.. but I'll deal with that later) but for some reason the media gallery is showing the images as 1px by 1px.. these values are hardcoded into the image tag itself.

eg:

```
<span class="media-icon image-icon"><img width="1" height="1" alt="" class="attachment-60x60" src="http://www.example.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/oct-2010-0161.jpg"></span>
```

The image exists, and so does the thumbnail, it's just not displaying properly in the Media.

Also, it looks like the old/current site is trying to use the 150x150 version of the image instead of the full size one the dev site is trying to use?  no idea what's up with that

I deactivated the theme and all plugins but nothing fixed it.